# Want to handle iframe with Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I want to handle iframe using cypress. I'm getting iframe and also clicked a button there. But when it comes to enter text in a textbox I'm getting error. I've used two method here. Both are giving same result

```
 /// <reference types="cypress-iframe"/>
import "cypress-iframe"
describe("Handling iframes", ()=>{
    it("Approach1", ()=>{
        cy.visit("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/AutomationPractice/");
        
        let iframe = cy.get("#courses-iframe").its("0.contentDocument.body").should("be.visible").then(cy.wrap)
        iframe.find("a[href*='consulting']").eq(0).should("be.visible").click()
        iframe.find("#username").type("shishir")
    })
    it.only("Approach2", ()=>{

        cy.visit("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/AutomationPractice/")
        cy.frameLoaded("#courses-iframe");
        cy.iframe().find("a[href*='consulting']").eq(0).click()
        cy.iframe().find("#username").type("shishir")
    })
})
```

[image: This is cypress saying]